# How to edit the (on delete cascade ) about a column on table

Tags: mysql, database

i have a simple database with columns like bus , user 
 
i want to edit bus column **ON DELETE RESTRICT** , how to do that , should i use update query or what please help me , am new to database.

Comment: Can you add your table definitions to your question (as text)?

Comment: well thank u very much for ur want to help , i solved the problem , i imported the whole database , then in the creation query of the table i added what i want , instead of using update or any thing :) . @P.Salmon